# What would be a word between 'opposite' and 'next to?'

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms

If you had two people sitting at ninety degrees to each other (see the attached image), they wouldn't be opposite each other, but they wouldn't be next to each other either. Is there an English word for the position they'd be in? (The arrows represent the way they are facing).[image]

An example sentence: they were sitting _____ to each other.

Comment: If there’s nobody in between them and the distance between them is a cbair’s width or less, then they ***are*** next to each other

Comment: is that green and red dot supposed to be a table?

Answer (score 1):

Probably the most common would be to say they are situated [**diagonally**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/diagonally).

---

There's another set of expressions you could use, kitty corner(ed)/catty corner(ed)/cater corner(ed):

> *North American*
>   Situated diagonally opposite someone or something.
>   <sub>[Oxford Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/cater-cornered)</sub>

All these expressions are synonymous but vary [depending on region](https://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/kitty-corner-or-catty-corner).

Answer (score 0):

You can say they are ‘sitting adjacent to one another’. It means ‘next to, but not facing’.

https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/adjacent

If you look up ‘adjacent angles’, you’ll get the idea:

https://www.mathsisfun.com/definitions/adjacent-angles.html